# Is it safe to cache public key used to sign a token in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) protected by Azure AD B2C. Using MSAL, I am getting the id token on the client side which I am sending to the backend API on each request.

I would like to validate the token on the backend as well and came across this code on GitHub: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/on-behalf-of/web-api/index.js.

One thing it does here is get the signing key using a code like following:

```
const getSigningKeys = (header, callback) => {
        var client = jwksClient({
            jwksUri: discoveryKeysEndpoint,
        });

        client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (err, key) {
            var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
            callback(null, signingKey);
        });
    }
```

For Azure AD B2C, here's what I found in the documentation regarding validating the Id token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#validate-the-id-token.

When I execute the request in the browser for my B2C tenant and sign-in policy, I got some JSON back which looks something like the following:

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kid":"xxxx",
      "nbf":1493763266,
      "use":"sig",
      "kty":"RSA",
      "e":"AQAB",
      "n":"yyyy"
    }
  ]
}
```

Considering I would need to validate the token on each request and a network request needs to be made to get this information which could add some delay in getting the API response, I am wondering about caching it by storing it in environment variables.

Can I do that? Or does this information changes? Unfortunately the documentation does not mention anything regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively safe. The information could change, but it's likely to be (very) infrequent.

If you're using `jwks-rsa` as that example seems to then that comes with [caching built-in and enabled by default](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#caching), so you shouldn't need to worry about setting it up yourself (unless you want a different behaviour than it provides of course).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you point me to some documentation which talks about how frequently does this information change? Regarding in-built caching, my API is in Serverless environment. I guess if my Serverless environment remains hot (i.e. constantly getting invoked), I need not worry about caching it myself.

Comment: @GauravMantri unfortunately I don't think there are any docs that talk about it explicitly. If you're using custom policies then the key value exposed there comes from [the token signing key you create during tenant setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#create-the-signing-key), so it'll only change if you change that. For user flows I _believe_ that's controlled my Microsoft but I don't think I've ever seen any docs that details _how_.

Comment: With regard to caching/validation in your API, you're right as long as your API remains warm then you don't need to worry about it. You generally wouldn't expect to receive a valid token with a signing key that either wasn't in the cache or wasn't available from the jwks endpoint, if you do then that token is invalid and the client should obtain and submit a new one. If your API is called infrequently enough that it's unloading the cache after each call then the jwks endpoint _probably_ isn't the most expensive part of your API warming up to serve an incoming request anyway.